# Ruby on Rails. Why schema.rb builded on existing data through db:schema:dump is almost empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to find the correct (any) method to create an application in **Ruby on Rails** having an existing database (**PostgreSQL**) with data and fresh app made with:

```sh
rails new --database=postgresql -J --skip-coffee .
```

I found https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold but first I need to have a file with a database structure: `schema.rb`. I’m looking for a way to do it automatically.

In result of `rake db:schema:dump`file `schema.rb` is generated, but only with content like that:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
end
```

And I stuck here. Why that file is empty? Why are there no tables here?

I have a connection with DB and no errors.  I did `rake db:create` before to test. Creation of bases described in `database.yml` is successful.

At the beginning I used Docker containers and this is my goal. But to exclude the probability of error, I installed the environment in the system (macOS Mojave) based on the **socket**. And I’ve got the same effect.

How to generate `schema.rb` with structure of existing database? Or is there different way to build RoR app based on the existing data structure?

---

**Update**: Connection with the new database I only did for testing purposes. To verify configuration.

Here's what else I did:

1. Dump existing structure with
   `pg_dump --schema-only app_development > db/structure.sql`
2. I changed name in `database.yml` to have fresh place to import.
3. `rake db:setup` created new DB
4. `rake db:structure:load` create tables from `db/structure.sql` file in DB correctly.

But `rake db:schema:dump` still generate empty file as earlier.

Comment: What sort of stuff is in your structure.sql? "db/schema.rb cannot express everything your database may support such as triggers, sequences, stored procedures, check constraints, etc." https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it! Two days of my life. 
File used to import PostgreSQL database has at the beginning:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA employees;
-- and later
CREATE TABLE employees.department;
```

I thought that since Rails generates database by `rake db:structure:load` , the file's syntax is correct.

But when I create manually table `users` in new empty database and then `pg_dump` that new base I don't have `CREATE SCHEMA` query there.

And finally `rake db:schema:dump` fills `schema.rb` with tables as I want:

```rb
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text "name"
end
```

Because that fresh `pg_dump`ed file has `CREATE TABLE public.users` query. **public**.

I think the key is in comments in `database.yml` file:

```rb
# Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
#schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public
```

One picture is more valuable than a thousand words: [that's the differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snbfq.png) Table `users` on the right goes to `schema.rb` after `rake db:schema:dump`

Thanks guys for the comments. It's made sure me that I do not make a terrible mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set proper db config you can use `rake db:migrate` to regenerate the schema file.

*edit:*

Ok so lets check if I understood correctly:

- you have an existing db with tables and data in it
- you have brand new rails app
- you want to reflect db structure in you `schema.rb` file

Is that correct? If yes then like I wrote before - without adding any new migrations to your codebase, run `rake db:migrate`. That task not only applies changes from the migration file but also `updates` your schema file to be in sync with the actual database.

Comment: I think that's not the way. I don't have filled any migration files. I would like to generate them with gem **schema to scaffold** but it want to has tables in `schema.rb`. Please see the update of my question.

Comment: You understand well but I think I found the guilty one. BTW with `rake db:migrate` I had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did `rake db:create` which creates a new database for you and then did `rake db:schema:dump` which generated a `schema.rb` file for you from the newly created (empty) database.

If you have an existing database that you want to use you will need to modify your `database.yml` file to connect to it.

If you want to create a new database you will need to generate [Active Record database migrations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) e.g.) `rails generate migration CreateProducts name:string part_number:string` and then run them `rake db:migrate` to update your database and generate your `schema.rb`.

Comment: You have right but connection with the new database I only did for testing purposes. To verify configuration. Please see the update of my question for a few details.